# Composer Update - Could not load package shopware/shopware in http://packagist.org:

Tags: symfony, laravel, composer-php, updates

When i do composer update on my Laravel 5.1 it come out with this error

```
> Downloading http://packagist.org/p/symfony/polyfill-mbstring$a9a5f6e4a8af44008f50a8c0059a6d1a61b1f692627fb41f0cc1f3e8bbfb7205.json
> Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-mbstring.json into cache



  [RuntimeException]
  Could not load package shopware/shopware in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ~v
  2.0.0-rc1: Invalid version string "~v2.0.0-rc1"




[UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint ~v2.0.0-rc1: Invalid version string "~v2.0.0-rc1"
```

when i trace it on cache folder

```
"require-dev": {
                    "phpunit\/phpunit": "~4.5",
                    "phpunit\/dbunit": "~1.3",
                    "behat\/mink": "~1.7",
                    "behat\/mink-extension": "~2.1",
                    "behat\/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
                    "behat\/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.3",
                    "symfony\/dom-crawler": "~2.8",
                    "behat\/behat": "~3.1",
                    "sensiolabs\/behat-page-object-extension": "~v2.0.0-rc1"
                },
```

it is on not on my require package : composer.json
it is from symfony/polyfill-mbstring 
but why on json file they got this?

```
"packages": {
    "shopware\/shopware": {
        "5.2.x-dev": {
            "name": "shopware\/shopware",
            "description": "Shopware is the next generation of open source e-commerce software made in Germany",
            "keywords": ["shop", "shopware"],
            "homepage": "http:\/\/www.shopware.com",
            "version": "5.2.x-dev",
            "version_normalized": "5.2.9999999.9999999-dev",
            "license": ["AGPL-3.0", "proprietary"],
            "authors": [],
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https:\/\/github.com\/shopware\/shopware.git",
                "reference": "4c4817979a98144e57d9eebc5aa166795e378a1c"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/shopware\/shopware\/zipball\/4c4817979a98144e57d9eebc5aa166795e378a1c",
                "reference": "4c4817979a98144e57d9eebc5aa166795e378a1c",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "type": "project",
            "time": "2016-03-29T06:54:10+00:00",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-0": {
                    "Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\AbstractProxyFactory": "engine\/Library\/",
                    "Doctrine\\ORM\\Persisters\\Entity\\BasicEntityPersister": "engine\/Library\/",
                    "Shopware": "engine\/",
                    "Enlight": "engine\/Library\/",
                    "Zend": "engine\/Library\/",
                    "JSMin": "engine\/Library\/minify\/"
                },
                "classmap": ["engine\/Shopware\/Core\/"],
                "files": ["engine\/Shopware\/Application.php"]
            },
            "include-path": ["engine\/Library\/"],
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.5.9",
                "ext-curl": "*",
                "ext-mbstring": "*",
                "ext-gd": "*",
                "doctrine\/common": "2.5.1",
                "doctrine\/dbal": "2.5.1",
                "doctrine\/orm": "2.5.1",
                "beberlei\/assert": "2.4.0",
                "zendframework\/zend-escaper": "2.5.1",
                "oyejorge\/less.php": "1.7.0.5",
                "guzzlehttp\/guzzle": "5.1.0",
                "egulias\/email-validator": "1.2.9",
                "symfony\/http-kernel": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/config": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/dependency-injection": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/validator": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/filesystem": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/finder": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/console": "2.8.0",
                "symfony\/polyfill-php56": "1.0.0",
                "monolog\/monolog": "1.17.2",
                "doctrine\/cache": "1.6.0",
                "paragonie\/random_compat": "1.1.5",
                "symfony\/form": "2.8.0",
                "league\/flysystem": "1.0.18",
                "elasticsearch\/elasticsearch": "2.1.5",
                "ongr\/elasticsearch-dsl": "v2.0.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit\/phpunit": "~4.5",
                "phpunit\/dbunit": "~1.3",
                "behat\/mink": "~1.7",
                "behat\/mink-extension": "~2.1",
                "behat\/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
                "behat\/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.3",
                "symfony\/dom-crawler": "~2.8",
                "behat\/behat": "~3.1",
                "sensiolabs\/behat-page-object-extension": "~v2.0.0-rc1"
            },
            "replace": {
                "symfony\/polyfill-php55": "~1.0",
                "symfony\/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0"
            },
            "uid": 588566
        }, bla ...............
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had exact same error

`./composer.phar selfupdate` solve the problem, for me.

Comment: I can confirm that updating my Satis to the most current version fixes the problem for me - seems like an updated version constraint check in Composer.

Comment: @VaL can you tell me what version of your composer? now

Comment: @EnDiwang `Composer version 1.0-dev (e8b1a5f35772e39ca21ab855a278bd84a0a534b2) 2016-03-29 07:53:57`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with composer itself, we had the same problem with our global composer.
You will need to clear the cache and vendor maps in /root/.composer/ and update composer itself:

```
cd /root
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php --
php composer.phar global update
rm composer.phar
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. but i already do clear cache and update the composer .. still got the error 
actually im using centos 6.7

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* an issue in Composer but with the Shopware upstream packages.

The following commit broke this dependency on March 29th:
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/commit/e44e4a7d788675489aadbd664c50a7cfc47e0f05

The following commit fixed it a day later:
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/commit/0cec1d69e972150b3d1fa71b82e621031ff341e3

So if you are still experiencing this issue use the following commands to fix:

```
composer clear-cache
composer update shopware/shopware
```